# animationImages not working with Retina screens

Tags: ios, uiimageview

My app is doing fine displaying the "@2x" version of images appropriately on the Retina display, except when I use "animationImages".  On Retina screens, it displays these animationImages twice as large as they should be.  Is this a bug?  Or am I doing something wrong here?

```
-(void)viewDidLoad;

coransStar1 = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(46, 272, 48, 45)]     autorelease];
coransStar1.image = starImage;
coransStar1.opaque = YES;
NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star1"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star2"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star3"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star4"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star5"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star6"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star7"],
                         [UIImage imageNamed:@"star8"],
                         nil];

coransStar1.animationImages = imageArray;
coransStar1.animationDuration = 1.1;
coransStar1.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;


[coransView addSubview:coransStar1];
[coransStar1 startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was this line: coransStar1.image = starImage;

I'm not sure why, but when I removed that line (which shouldn't have been there in the first place, the problem went away.